# My deposits arrived in a steam program account

Tags: wallet, solflare

I tried transferring some sol into a Solflare account. It wound up in a “system program” account. How do I get it back?

Answer (score 1):

System program is a native Solana program that is responsible for some important and common actions, most notably -- Creating your Solana accounts. I think you are confusing something here. Your deposit on your Solflare wallet address is in your Solana account, which is created and owned by System program, and thats totally normal and fine.
[image]
You can search your Solana wallet address on Solscan and see the System program is the owner, as its responsible for allowing your account to perform common actions like transferring SOL.

If you are still confused, can you edit your question to attach a screen shot?